# Skip int element in array if it is equal to 6 when printing

Tags: java, arrays, int

I want to skip element when printing, if value of this element is equal to 6. Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

```
public class Task3_Killing_6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {2,4,5,6,8,6,3,4,6};
        int[] killSix = new int [9];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if(array[i] == 6){
                continue;
            } else {
                killSix[i] = array[i]; 
            }

        }

        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(killSix));
    }

}
```

And result is

```
[2, 4, 5, 0, 8, 0, 3, 4, 0]
```

I want to be

```
[2, 4, 5, 8, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because the array is initialised with 9 elements and they all get default values (i.e.0).

We need to use the list as we don't know the size. This should fix it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = { 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 6, 3, 4, 6 };
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] == 6) {
                continue;
            } 
            list.add(array[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Comment: This is for my homework (I'm a newbie), and have to do with basic knowledge that I have

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `List`.

**Note:** When you use `continue` then there is no more need for `else`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] array = {2,4,5,6,8,6,3,4,6};
    List<Integer> killSix = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if(array[i] == 6){
            continue;
        }
        killSix.add(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(killSix);
}
```

and the result is:

```
[2, 4, 5, 8, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This is for my homework (I'm a newbie), and have to do with basic knowledge that I have

Answer (score 0):

The central problem is that you used the same index for the old and new arrays.  This forces the new array to have 9 elements, but with 0's where you used to have 6's.

Instead, the new array has to have its own indexing system, or simply use the built-in array-building functions.

Also, you have a serious "code smell" at

```
if (array[i] == 6) {
    continue;
```

Any time you have a statement like "if **this**, do nothing; else do something", you should almost certainly reverse your logic.

Finally, please check your loop termination condition: I think you stop one element early.  Switch the last two elements in **array** as a test.

Initialize killSix to be an empty array.  Then change your central loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] != 6) {
        killSix.add(array[i]);
    }
```